# Configuring WordPress permissions for easy updates

Tags: permissions, ssh

I've been tasked with configuring a LAMP stack on a dedicated server to run multiple WordPress sites. Each site is attached to it's own SSH account.

I'm having trouble setting permissions that'll allow each user to easily perform updates, plugin installs and updates, and the like from within WordPress.

Normally I'd configure www-data to own the files, but that's not an option, and setting the www-data group as group owner of the files doesn't seem to work either. Nor does it seem to work when I install the SSH2 extension for PHP, and frankly I'd prefer to go around that. 
I can get it to work for plugin installs and updates if I install [this plugin](http://yoast.com/fix-automatic-plugin-update/), but there's got to be a way around that.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I haven't really been able to find any helpful articles via Google or WordPress' own forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes have a look at SuPHP http://www.suphp.org/Home.html, this should be on serverfault, not really a WordPress question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That seems to solve the problem I'm having. And I'll look into which questions goes were in the future.